# HttpClient PostAsync is blocking

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to call `HttpClient.PostAsync()` from my UI thread.  I have tested this on my development machine and it works fine but on my target machine is seems to block the UI thread. I ran this test on both machines

```
int tick = Environment.TickCount;
Task<HttpResponseMessage> postTask = _httpClient.PostAsync(Uri,
    new StringContent(messageString));
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Time {0}", Environment.TickCount - tick));
response = await postTask;
```

On my development machine the message box shows ~<100ms however on the target machine it is excess of 2.5 seconds.  Is there something that I am missing or is there some setting/OS/hardware support required.

Comment: You would have to use ConfigureAwait(false) for every await in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code, including all third- and second-party code. Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock

Comment: @bolkay, they get the task from the post then await it later.

Comment: I believe there is a portion of `PostAsync` that has to run before it posts its continuation and yields back control. From memory I think it has to obtain proxy server information (which may be different on your target machine) and resolve DNS before it yields. At least for the first call. For subsequent calls it ought to be cached. Are you seeing the same results repeatedly?

Comment: @JohnWu It appears to delay the first request after the application is started.  I dont notice any delay on following requests but they also happen very fast so I cant say if the following requests are still blocking or if they just happen fast enough not to notice.  One thing I know is there is authentication that has to happen for the first interaction.  This is directly connected to the Http server on LAN and the Uri is a static IP address

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a problem with a DNS lookup and as pointed out in the comments will likely cache for future calls, if you absolutely need this to **not** block the UI.

The only solution to this is to *offload* it (at the expense of a thread pool thread)..

```
var postTask = await Task.Run(() => _httpClient.PostAsync(Uri, new StringContent(messageString)));
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference I think I found the solution.  It looks like the time was being taken in `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint()` which is called creating the `WebRequest`.  I noticed that configuring my target machine with a proper gateway resolved the speed issue however in my case the machine will not always be connected to a larger LAN or internet so I figured out if you set `HttpClientHandler.UseProxies` to `false` it skips trying to find a proxy server and it now returns in ~32ms.

Odd that they wouldn't have the `FindServicePoint()` `async` but that seemed to be the issue.  I thought that with my Uri being a fixed ip i.e. `http://192.168.250.1:80/...` I would bypass all that stuff but not the case